# Show search results that include search criteria

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have coded a search for my page, however i am wanting this to showproducts that contain the search criteria... At the moment it only shows results that begin with the cirteria.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["q"];
if ($name <= "") {
  echo ("");
}
else {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cl49-XXX", "vogalcms");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con) or die("Unable to select database");   
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
  mysql_select_db("cl49-vogalcms", $con) or die("Unable to select database");   


  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prodID = $row['prodID'];
    $prodname = $row['prodname'];
    $catagory = $row['catagory'];
    echo "
     <div class='row-fluid portfolio-block'>
    <div class='span5 portfolio-text'>
    <img src='admin/userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='50' width='50' alt='' />
    <div class='portfolio-text-info'>
                                                <h4>$prodname</h4>
    <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class='span5'>
<div class='portfolio-info'>
Product ID
                                                <span>$prodID</span>
        </div>
  <div class='portfolio-info'>
                                                catagory
                                                <span>$catagory</span>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class='span2 portfolio-btn'>
  <a href='edit_product.php?q=$prodID' class='btn bigicn-only'><span>View/Edit</span></a>
    </div>
    </div> ";
  }
}
?>
```

I would like to be able to search ca and not just show CAr, CArpet but also show nesCAfe?

Comment: Again and again and again, escape your variables in SQL. mysql_* is deprecated. Dont use fetch_array where it is not needed. Which tutorials are you guys coming from, always same never ending mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your where clause to this:

```
WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%$name%'
```

Comment: I already have this? 
`("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ")`

Comment: There are two %s - the % at the start of the LIKE statement is what makes the difference. Try it. :)

Comment: Brill! thanks! also, do you know how to show something like `22 found` (22 is an example of products found)

Comment: do something like: `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: that'll give you a variable that has the number of records returned, which you can then output :)

Comment: sorry, novice here :( how do i output it?

Comment: just do: echo $num_rows.' found';

Answer (score 1):

Change your search query to

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%$name%'
```

Comment: i already have this? `("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ")`

Comment: There is extra `%` (2 %) in my answer '%$name%'. Using `%` befor and after the keyword will match whole keywords. If you are confused you can refer this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/